# Script to create database xmla file

Tags: c#, powershell, ssms, ssas, xmla

I'm looking for an automatic method for generating the file that is created in the first screenshot to see if it can be done:

[image: Manual method for generating file in SSMS]

It is an **xmla** file detailing the structure of the tables within the database. Preferably a solution in **C#** or **PowerShell**, but any method would be appreciated.

The second image is the format of the desired output file. This is easily generated from SSMS but I would like to run a script to generate this instead:

[image: Desired xmla output file]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does the xmla file contain if you try to open it with a text editor? XML? SQL?

Comment: Does this answer in StackExchange help?
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51129/script-out-xmla-for-all-databases

Comment: I've attatched above the xmla file that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using *SQL Server Analysis Services* database:**

In **C#** you can use [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/amo/developing-with-analysis-management-objects-amo?view=asallproducts-allversions) package as follow:

```
Server yourServer = new Server();
yourServer.Connect(@"Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName");

MajorObject[] yourDatabase = new MajorObject[1];
yourDatabase[0] = yourServer.Databases["DbName"];

var scripter = new Scripter();
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"FilePath")
```

Take a look at the following link. The question is similar to your one:

[Need c# script for SMO which creates XMLA script from analysis service database](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/df4502fa-2e5c-4765-ba3a-ad37987abd56/need-c-script-for-smo-which-creates-xmla-script-from-analysis-service-database?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

---

**If you are using *SQL Server* database:**

In **C#** you can use [Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15) package to generate script for database objects as follow:

[SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
Server yourServer = new Server("ServerName");

Scripter scripter = new Scripter(yourServer);

Database yourDb = yourServer.Databases["DbName"];

foreach (Table table in yourDb.Tables)
{
    tableScripts = table.Script();
    foreach (string script in tableScripts)
        Console.WriteLine(script);
}
```

You can also use **scripting options** to `IfNotExists` , `ScriptDrops`, and so on. I suggest you to take a look at the following links:

[Generate Scripts for database objects with SMO for SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1833/generate-scripts-for-database-objects-with-smo-for-sql-server/)

[Scripting Database Objects using SMO](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated)

And then, you can create your script file using **C#** code.